# log4j appender relative to the path of my maven project

Tags: maven, log4j, relative-path, appender

I'm trying to define an log4j appender to be saved in my current maven project (for dev only). I do not want the appender to end up in my deployed webapp, but in my actual maven project, next to the sources, regardless of where my webapp is deployed (locally of course).

I have tried various maven (and non-maven) variables with no luck.

Is there a variable I'm missing to do this simply?
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting `${basedir}` or `${basedir}/target` as the logfile location in log4j.properties? It should get filtered during the build.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately. Is this working for you? Thanks

Comment: The property resolves to an empty string. This does make sense, because the entire logging context is initialized within the deployed webapp, in the web server, where ${basedir} doesn't mean anything. On the other hand, I be missing something. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any files you put in `src/main/resources` will get copied (as part of the Maven build) to target/classes when you build, and strings like `${basedir}` should get filtered (i.e. replaced).

Comment: So you're saying that ${basedir} will still point to the sources even when the application is deployed? I will give it a go with a sample script, to see what's wrong, because it didn't work initially. 
Thanks.

Comment: It should do. Check in your `target` directory for the filtered version of the file. If filtering is working, `{basedir}` should have been replaced with an actual path. You might need to explicitly configure the maven resources plugin but I thought it had sensible defaults.